# ghost error with db file

Tags: sqlite, ghost-blog

I am trying to run ghost on the localhost. When I am doing

> npm start

I am getting the below error.

> ERROR: Unable to open sqlite3 database file for read/write   EACCES,
>   permission denied
>   '/home/letsalign/Projects/letsalign-blog/content/data/ghost-dev.db'
>
> Check that the sqlite3 database file permissions allow read and write
>   access.

Although the db has the read and write permission.

Please help

Comment: You ran `npm install --production` before `npm start`?

Comment: @mikedidthis yes, I did.. that didn't cause any issues.

Comment: My only other suggestion would be `npm start --production`. You confirmed read / write permissions on the DB file.

Comment: I did chmod u+w <filename> to make sure it is that way, even though it has the read write permission.

http://imgur.com/ItwnwFs check the image screenshot

Comment: Hmm you could ask here: https://github.com/tryghost/Ghost/issues

Comment: What user are you using when starting Ghost?  It looks like you are using the user letsalign and it only has read only on the database.